# point is within circle in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to find out whether a point is within the circle or not using postgresql.
For point within polygon, I have used following query. i need some equivalent query for circle too.

```
SELECT a
FROM a_table
WHERE 
ST_within(a::geometry,ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((50 -80.98 , 20.99 -90.99 , 90.98 -99.99 , 50 -80.98))'));
```

for circle, i tried this below query :

```
SELECT a
FROM a_table
WHERE 
ST_within(a::geometry,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10 20)',10));
```

and

```
SELECT a
FROM a_table
WHERE 
ST_within(a::geometry,ST_GeomFromText('circle((10 20),10)'));
```

but both of these gives errors like this :

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000
Hint: "714" <-- parse error at position 4 within geometry
```

and

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000
Hint: "ci" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

Comment: Its not clear whether you are using PostGIS's geometries or PostgreSQL's geometries. They are very different, and cannot be mixed. Furthermore, to search whether a point is within a radius of another, use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to specify the distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a
from a_table
where a <@ circle '((10, 20),10))';
```

[Geometric Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html)

```
select point '(1,1)' <@ circle '((0,0), 1)';
 ?column? 
----------
 f

select point '(1,1)' <@ circle '((0,0), 1.5)';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: in my query a is a column name of type "point" in postgresql.  and your query is also not working .

Comment: @hina It was missing a comma. Try again

Comment: are u sure, about this query, why we are using <@ , can you please elaborate how this query works in postgresql

Comment: @hina Check the Geometric operators and functions link in my updated answer

Comment: can you tell me, what is the unit of radius considered in your above query.

Comment: @hina It is the same unit you use to store the points. If the points are stored in kilometers then it is kilometers.

Comment: the points, i m storing are latitude and longitude on map, so what will be the unit for radius in this case?

Comment: @hina Then it will be degrees